# x86 Assembly - about procedures

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I have a question about procedures. Let's say I make a procedure, will it only work if I call it or jump to it or will it work normally like a label?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "work normally like a label"? How would this be any different than jumping to a procedure?

Comment: TASM has a bunch of PROC stuff to help you, you can ignore all of it and write code however you like, in fact organizing your code into procedures at all isn't necessary (just useful).

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

If it uses a ret instuction then it expects a return addr was pushed onto the stack...so jmp'ing to it without pushing that would cause a stack problem.

Comment: A procedure without a call and without a ret, think of it as a label. You just jump to it but instead of being a label, it is a procedure.

Comment: Sounds like you have it under control...perhaps test it and come back when you have a problem or a more specific question.

Comment: Well, you can jump to it from any other procedure, but without a `CALL` and a `RET` you can only hard code a single destination at its end. So it's not a procedure.

Comment: @Weather Vane Couldn't you do something like..assume 2 registers are set to 2 different return locations; jmp to one on success, and jmp to the other on error/problem. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @ABuckau: yes, you can build a custom calling convention if you like, by passing jump targets in registers.  (emulating RISC-style link register).  However, that defeats the return-address predictor, so you're more likely to get branch mispredicts.  Passing two possible jump targets is interesting, but the it ties up two registers in the called function (or is yet another thing for it to spill/reload).  I can't see this ever performing better than a normal `call` and test&branch on a normal return value.  It's a bit like an exception handler, but there are better ways to implement exceptions.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thank you for the detailed response. @ Weather Vane perhaps be more careful when using words like only/always/never etc.

Comment: Weathervane was probably ruling that out indirect jumps because it's not a good idea in practice :P  The statement is accurate if you're only considering the case of ending a PROC block with a direct `jmp` to somewhere.  (like if a static function has only one call-site, you could replace the call/ret with jmp/jmp, if for some reason you didn't want to just inline it.)

Comment: Possibly, but can't and shouldn't are very different.

Comment: If you want to argue semantics, I said "only *hard* code". You could do it by pushing the return address first, but that adds more code overhead when there is a perfectly good `call` instruction to do it for you. The situation is somewhat like using macros to redefine a programming language.

Comment: Jumping to a procedure can have a benefit where code space is very tight. Suppose a set of similar procedures all call a common "clean up" procedure before returning. Jumping into it, instead of calling, will allowing its `RET` instruction to save one `RET` instruction in each of the afore-mentioned.